# Populate ListView by getting the string in textView

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview, an autocomplete textview and a button in my app. After putting a word in my textview (by the use of imagebutton) when i click the button the word in the textview should be transferred in the listview and well, erase it on textview. How can i do thaT?

I am new to android programming. Any suggetions will be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the corresponding views in `onCreate` method

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_img);
TextView txt = findViewById(R.id.txt_word);
ListView lst = findViewById(R.id.list_words);
```

Next create an Adapter for listview and bind it together

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdater(context,android.R.id.simple_list_item_1,new ArrayList<String>());

lst.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Finally, set the btn to perform the desired function

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @overrides
    public void onClick(View v){
      adapter.add(txt.getText().toString());
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      txt.setText("");
    }
});
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: error: simple_list_item_1 cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Comment: it should be `android.R.id.simple_list_item_1` its an android in-built layout and will be present in every android framework

Comment: It doesnt add the new word. whenever i try to have a new word in my textview it only shows the new word. how can i make it like alist? adding the new word without deleting or replacing the first word?

Comment: it wont delete.. i guess your `listview` has `layout_height` set to `wrap_content`. This only shows only 1 item. Try scrolling in the 1 item. and also set the height bigger or `match_parent`

Comment: i did it this way 
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,new ArrayList<String>());

because there is an error whenver i use  R.id. 

its working now but whenver i have a new word on my textview, it replaces the first word .. I want it to add (like a list) not replace. how can i do that?

Comment: itll add. try scrolling the listview in the application. it should be there.. try setting the height

Comment: Can i make the text smaller? It's so big and I can't scroll it .  I already set it as match_parent

Comment: text size as big as the size of parent ??

Comment: to control the size you have to implement a manual layout or custom adapter. :-/

Comment: okay i'll try it again .. one last question. after clicking the button the textview of course erases the text on it. but when putting/inserting new letter the word that is supposed to be erased gets bakc and only adds the letter. like "THANK" and when i try to create a new word it looks like this "THANKYOU". why is it like that?

Comment: i did not understand u

Comment: for example:
my first word is "Hello", clicked the button and the textview is cleared/ empty (txt.setText("");). 
I wanted to construct a new word on my textview like "World".

It should only display the newly constructed word which is "World" but in my case, it displays the firstword+the new wor which is == HelloWorld.

Comment: this problem is from how you are inserting your words to the textview, from how i understand you, you add using imagebutton, and the in the "method of adding strings" is not cleared but the text on the textview is cleared, so when you attempt another adddition, using "method of adding strings"it adds all.. i know its been 16 days, maybe you have moved on but, just trying to elaborate.@LabLey

Answer (score 0):

Once you click the image button, get the value from the textview and commit data to a database table, then reload the listview by filling data from database and set empty string to the textview

if you need source code i would like to help you with that, first you should try, and lets wait more answers, anyone better than me

cheers